# What is this capo-like guitar accessory?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

[image]

What is this guitar accessory on 13th fret?

Comment: It's actually going to be touching on  (over) fret 14 - as the lower capo is on fret 2. Thus giving the 2nd harmonic on 'open' strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a special capodastro varient with which you can capo individual strings. Such capos are called partial capos. I can't say for sure, but the product name of the one in the video is probably "spider capo".

In the photo it appears that the three higher strings are capo-ed at the 13th or 14th fret while the lower three strings are not affected at this point (but are capo-ed at the 2nd fret). The resulting effect is the same like with a full capo, only with partial capos it is limited to the selected strings.

Comment: https://spidercapo.com/ Here’s the site

Comment: I was looking more into it. It's a really cool capo for playing harmonics as well. Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEtyjKtJxmg

Comment: @LuvAgarwal - that takes capoing to a whole new level. Love it!

Comment: @LuvAgarwal: I have a Spider Capo; unfortunately, while it makes possible to fret strings above or below the capo, I was disappointed to find that it doesn't allow individual notes to be fretted at on the same fret as the capo.  For example, when using standard tuning down two frets, fretting the top three strings on the second fret would allow one to play most chords as in standard, but gain an improved D chord.  Unfortunately, the capo would get in the way of playing a six-string E chord.

Comment: @supercat Useful info. Thanks. It looked a bit limited in that YouTube demo, and I wasn't sure if it was him not knowing quite what to do with it, or the limitations of the device itself. Have you found any uses for it?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I don't remember the last time I used it, but I mainly use an alternative tuning G-D-d-f-g#-b I designed to play movable chords, so I really don't play many open chords other than "D" chords that use the open low-D string.

Comment: @supercat What the - ? So I guess you need special strings to tune that high. I'm not a guitarist. (Well - classical. Badly.) I've just been reading about movable chords, which I hadn't heard of till you mentioned them. I get that idea now. But I didn't know a guitar could be tuned so high. I'll have to get a guitarist friend to explain all this! Your cat is among my pigeons.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Relative to standard tuning, the strings are +3 -7 +0 -2 -3 -5; to achieve decent tension, one should at minimum swap the bottom two strings of a standard set (in which case they would both be two frets below their normal tension).

Comment: @supercat: OK! I get it! Swapping the bottom two, yes. I didn't realize the standard A was now D *below* standard E, so I thought you had an octave gap from D to d! OK. And I guess you use two B-strings. It's an interesting tuning, and if my guitar hadn't been stolen I would be playing around with it all night.What's the advantage of G-D at the bottom, rather than D-G?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: The advantage of swapping those two strings is that it makes it easy to strum the D-d-f-g#-b strings without having to fret or mute the G string.

Comment: @supercat: Yeah of course. Thanks. And thank you for all the above. Very interesting.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: Search youtube for "flat finger world" or "flat finger misty" to see a couple of examples of how movable chords are fingered with this tuning.  Both examples are just guitar--no bass player--but they end up with very satisfying bass lines anyhow.

Comment: @supercat: TVM. I'm on it.

Answer (score 0):

Spider Capo. I have it and I like it. You can capo individual strings.